# Blazor group validation

Tags: validation, blazor

I have this view model:

```
public class Model
{
  public int A1{ get; set; }
  public int A2{ get; set; }
  public int B1{ get; set; }
  public int B2{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to use [Required] validation that all fields or one of the two field groups is filled in:

- ((A1 and A2) and (B1 and B2)) OR
- ((A1 and A2) or (B1 and B2))

I hope it is clear.
Help me, please.

Comment: Hi sada. `int` will always have a value. Did you mean bool or nullable type?

Comment: Hi, Their values are from 1 to 23. It's a range. Thank you.